# Is “Master of Architecture Graduate” grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I want to state that I have graduated from university, and I have master’s degree.

Is it correct to state: “Master of Architecture Graduate” ???

And longer as: “Master of Architecture Graduate from SRBIAU...” ???

The part that bothers me and makes me think my sentence is wrong, is the “graduate” part, which I’m not sure if works in this context...

Comment: (I am an) M.Arch., SRBIAU

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for the British system.  In the UK the word *graduate* applies only to the first degree (the BA/BSc).  The normal way to express what you want to say is: *I have a Master’s degree in architecture from X University*.

Comment: I want to make it short as an statement, not a full sentence.

Comment: Then “MA or MSc in architecture from X university.”

Comment: And because a master's degree in architecture is separate from the arts and sciences (usually) you get to make it even shorter: M.Arch from X University.